# MySQL Master Slave configuration using Docker-compose

Tags: mysql, docker, nginx, docker-compose, master-slave

Okay so I wanted to make a master slave replication for mysql for my website hosted in nginx run by php. I've managed to connect to the master mysql however, there seems to have some error on my slave container. I was wondering if there is anything wrong or what I should add in order to solve this issue.

```
You need to specify one of MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD, MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD and MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD
2020-10-15 09:09:44+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 1:10.5.6+maria~focal started.
2020-10-15 09:09:45+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2020-10-15 09:09:45+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 1:10.5.6+maria~focal started.
2020-10-15 09:09:45+00:00 [ERROR] [Entrypoint]: Database is uninitialized and password option is not specified
You need to specify one of MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD, MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD and MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD
```

My docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "3.3"
  
services:

  mysql:

    image: mariadb:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_REPLICATION_MODE: master
      MYSQL_REPLICATION_USER: repl_user
      MYSQL_REPLICATION_PASSWORD: repl_password
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpw
      MYSQL_DATABASE: database
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: mypw
    networks:
      - my-net

  mysql-slave:
      image: mariadb:latest
      restart: always
      ports:
        - "3306"
      depends_on:
        - mysql
      environment:
         MYSQL_REPLICATION_MODE: slave
         MYSQL_REPLICATION_USER: repl_user
         MYSQL_REPLICATION_PASSWORD: repl_password
         MYSQL_MASTER_HOST: mysql
         MYSQL_MASTER_PORT_NUMBER: 3306
         MYSQL_MASTER_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpw
         MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpw
      networks:
        - my-net
  myphp:
    build: ./src/php
    restart: always
    expose:
      - "9000"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - mysql-slave
    networks:
      - my-net

  mynginx:
image: nginx
restart: always
volumes:
  - ./src/nginx.ini:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
  - ./src/php-fpm.conf:/etc/php/7.4/fpm/php-fpm.conf
  - ./src/www.conf:/etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
  - ./src:/var/www/html/
ports:
  - "8080:80"
depends_on:
  - myphp
networks:
  - my-net
```

networks:
my-net:
driver: bridge

Comment: read 'You need to specify one of M...' precisely, because you don't for the slave.

Comment: I added "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpw" in the slave however it still shows the same error